# Circuit that makes capacitors behave like inductor and vice versa

Tags: capacitor, inductor, gyrator

They can be used in ICs. I vaguely remember reading about it few months ago, but I cannot remember its name right now. Can anyone help?

Comment: Is it a gyrator you're thinking of?

Comment: Yes, thank you very much.

Comment: @VoltageSpike: Why was this closed. It was not a shopping question but a terminology question. Please reopen and I'll post an answer.

Comment: It's doesn't read any different than a question asking for a reccomendation, typically on the site we have closed questions like this. It was flagged for length, and someone already gave an answer in the comments.

Comment: @VoltageSpike Then IMHO best practice is to write an answer out of the comment answering the question. Because readers of this site tend to look for questions with answers. Unanswered questions often are not viewed.

Comment: @MarkU, I'm slightly bemused by the addition of the 'gyrator' tag given the question title. While i know you are correct,  I'm trying to imagine how it would be useful!

Answer (score 1):

The term you are looking for is "gyrator".

> A gyrator is a passive, linear, lossless, two-port electrical network element proposed in 1948 by Bernard D. H. Tellegen as a hypothetical fifth linear element after the resistor, capacitor, inductor and ideal transformer. ... Circuits that function as gyrators can be built with transistors and op-amps using feedback. Source: [Wikipedia - gyrator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gyrator).

Answer (score 0):

I think, the most popular circuit is a GIC (Generalized Impedance Converter) which can transfer one (grounded) capacitor into one (grounded) inductor. The GIC consists of two opamps - preferrably in a topology as proposed by Antoniou.

A "vice versa" transform (L into C) is, of course, possible. However, I doubt if this would make much sense. Up to now - I never have seen a corresponding application.